# How to defer the return of an inner function?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function which should return only after its inner function is called. How to? Please check the code below -

```
function a() {
  function b() {
  }
return something//this something has to be returned only after function b is called. b is called from another file.
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are dealing with async processing in `b`, you can't do that... instead of returning you should use promise/callback mechanisms

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I get that. But i cant use the promise defer thingy in the other file which calls the function b. thats a restriction.

Comment: then there is not much you can do about it

Comment: your comments make no sense.   How can `b` be called from another file when it's within the (private) lexical scope of `a` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `something` as a callback of `b`, then it will work as you want. Another way is using promises:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // run function b

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve();
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});
```

Then you can use `then` if the promise was fulfilled:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  return something;
}, function(err) {
  console.log("Failed");
});
```